# Bounded Stream like implementation in java

Tags: java, stream, queue, bounded-types

**Goal**:

1. I am looking for a bounded byte stream like implementation in java to have "write" and "read" functionality.
2. The write should be non-blocking and should drop if the capacity has been reached.
3. Ideally, the max size of the stream should be given in the beginning so that dynamic memory allocation overhead is not present.

**What I have tried**:

I have shared data structure using the following buffer class, shared between the producer and consumer:

```
public class Buffer<T> {

    private ArrayBlockingQueue<T> buffer;

    public Buffer(int maxSize) {
        buffer = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(maxSize);
    }

    public boolean offer(T o) {
        return buffer.offer(o);
    }

    public T take(){
        try {
            return buffer.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Buffer<String> buffer = new Buffer<String>(10);
        buffer.offer("hello");
        System.out.println(buffer.take());
    }

}
```

A Producer in Thread 1 which reads from a socket and sends data as follows:

```
private InputStream in;

while ( (bytesRead = in.read(request)) != -1) {
   this.register.buffer.offer(new ByteObject(request,bytesRead)
 }
```

A Consumer in Thread 2 which reads from the buffer and writes to a socket:

```
private OutputStream out;

while(true){
   ByteObject poll = register.buffer.take();
   bytesRead = poll.len;

   if(bytesRead>0){
       out.write(poll.arr,0,bytesRead);
       out.flush();
    }else
       break;
}
```

**Problem with current implementation:**

Since it is not a stream implementation, I am unable to detect EOF in the consumer. Can anyone give an example for Bounded Stream operations in java which give a non-blocking write option (like offer() functionality)

Alternatively, how would I get EOF in the current code?